# Authorize.net auto email receipts

Tags: payment-processor, receipts, authorize.net

I am using authorize.net as a payment processor. They have automatic receipt emails that go out after a contact makes a contribution. I have disabled them from going out on my account, but they are still going out. They said it was on the Civi side and something was over-riding that setting. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: To clarify: did you disable the automatic emails on your Authorize.net account or on Civi?  Also, what version of Civi and CMS are you using?

Comment: I did disable the emails on authorize.net. I am using version 4.4.3

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a problem with Authorize.Net receipts going out when I've disabled the appropriate setting in Authorize.Net.  I don't have a valid Authorize.Net login to find the exact setting now, but I can confirm that I've seen the behavior you expect on multiple sites.